# How to Copy a Local Directory to an Apache Server

Tags: directory, server, local, scp

I have a directory on my desktop and need to copy it to my server. I've looked up a command to do this being

scp -r /path/to/local/storage user@remote.host:/path/to/copy

but when I run it, it just tells me "No suck file or directory".

First of all is this the correct way to do this or is there an easier way to take a directory from local storage and put it onto an apache server? Once I get it on the server I can move it around just fine there. I just need to get it on there!

the path I'm using right now for local is

/Users/byw5k_000/Desktop/myWebsite

with myWebsite being the directory I want to copy onto my server.

I'm curious if I'm getting the path incorrect. What is the correct path to the desktop on a windows 10 computer and will this work for me to copy an entire directory onto an apache server?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing to your Desktop directory like this:

```
cd C:\Users\(username)\Desktop
```

and then running:

```
scp -r myWebsite user@remote.host:/path/to/copy
```

Should work as ling as you can change to your Desktop directory

Comment: Thanks, that actually made it pick up the directory. Only problem is now it is saying Permission denied when I try to run the command. I think it has to do with permission on the folder I'm putting it in or user I'm using to make the copy.